# How to append elements inside an anchor tag and enclosing a word using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, append

Basically I want to append `<span></span>` inside the anchor tag but outside of "home". I guess it should be easy but I just started using jQuery.

So this:

```
<li class="home"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
```

Should end up like this with Jquery:

```
<li class="home"><a href="index.php"><span>home</span></a></li>
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation"> 
   <li class="home"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
   <li class="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
   <li class="about"><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
   <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

My CSS:

```
ul#navigation {
 height: 20px;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100%;
}
ul#navigation li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}
ul#navigation li a {
 background: url(../images/tab.png);
 color: #C0C0C0;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 20px;
 outline: none;
 padding-left: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul#navigation li a:hover {
 background-position: 0 -20px;
 color: #666;
}
#home li.home a, #portfolio li.portfolio a{
 background-position: 0 -20px;
 color: #666;
}
ul#navigation span {
 background: url(../images/tab.png) 100% 0;
 display: block;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
ul#navigation li a:hover span {
 background-position: 100% -20px;
}
#home li.home span, #portfolio li.portfolio span {
 background-position: 100% -20px;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.home a').wrapInner('<span></span>')
});
```

Comment: is there a way to tell jQuery: wrap span tags around any text that is inside anchor tags?

Comment: which is the css rule that does not work?

Comment: Its OK now, I just changed li.home a to ul#navigation li a

Comment: One last comment - the question shouldn't be marked "community wiki", since you're not collecting opinions but rather asking for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("li.home a").wrapInner("<span></span>")
```

Somehow StackOverflow clears my markup. There should be`<span></span>` inside the 'wrap' call.

Comment: Sorry but that wraps the span tags around the anchor tags but not inside them

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Then you need wrapInner() , see http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner#html

Comment: @jano - wrapInner() will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but its a bit weird the css properties for the span tags that are added with jQuery are not being applied correctly is this normal?

Comment: no, this is not normal, there is something else about it. Can you post the CSS code you're using?

Comment: Oh never mind. I found out that it was just applied to li.home and not to the others. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.home a').each(function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<span>'+content+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: it almost worked but it rendered like this: "<span>[object Window]</span>"